# Percent variation of a physical quantity: how to choose who is in the denominator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, frequency

I came up with a very basic doubt on percent variation of a physical quantity,say $f$, defined as

$$\delta f_{\%}=|{\frac{\Delta f}{f}}|\cdot 100$$

The problem is with the denominator. I'll make a practical example.

I met in some problems on acoustic with the following sentence

> Consider that acoustic beats are heard only if the percentual difference between the two frequencies is less than $5\%$, that is $$ |{\frac{\Delta f}{f}}|<0.05$$

I do not understand what is the deniminator in this situation. I have two different frequencies $f_1$ and $f_2$, so $|\Delta f|=|f_1-f_2|=|f_2-f_1|$ but what about the $f$ below? Is it $f_1$ or $f_2$ ? What is the criteria to choose that?

Depending on the choose of the denominator, the range of frequencies for which we have beats is different so it's important. And it seems there is no a selection criteria between $f_1$ and $f_2$ because none of them is something like the "initial" frequency. The two of them are just there, playing the same role.

So how to deal with these situations? Is there a general rule to follow to choose who should be in the denominator between two values of the same physical quantity of which we want to find the percent variation?

Comment: I would chose $f=(f_1+f_2)/2$

Comment: The formula requires that you pick one frequency as the reference, and I wouldn't take the absolute of the variation. It is perfectly sensible to say that something deviates x percent up or y percent down. In general you want to give ranges as e.g. "-3%/+5%", because in many cases they are asymmetric for good reasons. If anything, I find forcing the absolute value into this highly unphysical and causing a significant loss of information.

Comment: It makes little difference. Yes, f should be the average, per Smitherson. And if you need the plus or minus more accurately you do as @CuriousOne says. More correctly when you have multiple freqs measured you'd do plus or minus 1 sigma over the average, for a 68% certainty, and use other higher sigma multiples for higher certainties from the Gaussian distribution. Your formula is just a simple case approximation, don't sweat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some experience in music, I realized that the relation of the frequency of two pitches with equal steps say from C to D (whole step) or D to E (same whole step) is 

$f_2 = af_1$, 

where $f_2$ is the higher pitch, and $f_1$ is the lower,
and $a$ depends only on the distance of steps from the lower to higher pitch.

This means that the frequency difference at higher pitches will be greater given the same distance of steps (say, the difference is higher in $F_3$ to $G_3$ than that in $C_3$ to $D_3$ and higher still in $F_4$ to $G_4$)

Let's say we have $f_2 = cf_1$, and $c$ is the threshold constant for $f_1$ so that for constants with values lesser than c, we will be able to hear beats from the two pitches. Then the condition must be
$$f_2<cf_1$$
$$f_2-f_1 < cf_1 - f_1$$
$$\frac{f_2-f_1}{f_1}<c-1$$
where $c-1 = 0.05$
which means $c = 1.05$

And it looks like we should have $f_1$ for the denominator..
I mean the one with lower frequency..

Answer (score 0):

The context of the question is acoustics, but that is irrelevant.  Essentially the same question could be posed in chemistry, biology, economics, etc.  No physical laws or concepts can solve this problem.  It is really a question about mathematics and the definition of "percentage difference."

The same issue crops up regularly in mathematics homework questions.  As you point out, the change is always expressed as a fraction of the initial value. The difficulty in this case is that we are not told which is the initial value. "Percentage difference" is not defined : what the difference is a fraction of is not identified.

In such situations generally, since it has not been specified which value is to be used in the denominator,  this implies that you should get the same final answer whichever you use.  So I would use both and round the answer accordingly.  If your final answer differs depending on whether you use $f_1$ or $f_2$ then you have not rounded it sufficiently.

In this case, since you are testing if $|\frac{\Delta f}{f}| < 0.05$, you should use the smaller of $f_1$ and $f_2$ - ie the one which which gives the larger fraction.  That way, you can be sure that both values give a fraction < 0.05.  If instead you are testing if $|\frac{\Delta f}{f}| > 0.05$ then you should use the larger of the two.